# Declaração Correta de Variável em document.getElementById() para @foreach

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, laravel

Olá, estou precisando chamar uma script dentro de uma página acionada por um botão usando método ajax.

Minha script em Javascript:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
function attachProjetoFuncionario()
{
    var id_projeto = document.getElementById("ajaxValueProjeto").value;
    var id_funcionario = document.getElementById("ajaxValueFuncionario").value;

    $.get('projeto/'+id_projeto+'/'+id_funcionario+'/attachProjetoFuncionario', function(data){
              console.log(data);

    var idProjeto = data.id_projeto;
    var idFuncionario = data.id_funcionario;
    })
}
</script>
```

A área em HTML que imprime as informações, em forma de cartões é a seguinte.

```html
<div>
<h5 style="margin-top: 12px; margin-bottom: 6px; text-align: left;"><strong>Funcionários Encarregados: </strong></h5>

        <?php
        $funcionarios = $projeto->Funcionarios;
        ?>

        <div id="ajaxCardsFuncionarios" style="margin-top: 20px; display: table">
            <div class="mb-6" style="display: table-row; ">
            @foreach($funcionarios as $fun)
                @if($fun->removido != 1)    

                <div class="card text-white bg-primary" style="min-width: 10rem; display: table-cell; float:left;">

                    <div class="card-header"><a href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/funcionario/{{ $fun->id }}/detailedFuncionario/" style="font-size: 25px">{{$fun->name}}</a></strong></div>

                    <div class="card-body">
                    <button style="margin-top: 2px; padding: .150rem .75rem" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick=" window.location.href = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/funcionario/{{$fun->id}}/atualizarFuncionario';" >Editar</button>

                    <!-- Botão de Remover -->
                    <button style="margin-top: 2px; padding: .150rem .75rem;" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#md{{$fun->id}}" class="btn btn-primary">Remover</button>
                    <!-- Fim dos Botões de Editar e Remover -->

                </div>
        </div>
        @endif
        @endforeach
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

A área da página em que se pode clicar para adicionar ou remover funcionários (dentro de um método de attach de informação extra) é a seguinte.

```html
<!-- Div Escolher Funcionários  -->
<center><div>
    <?php
    $fun = new App\Funcionario; 
    $funcionarios = App\Funcionario::all();
    ?>
{{ csrf_field() }}

<div style="margin-top: 20px; float: left;">

    <h4 style="margin-top: 18px">Atualizar Funcionários</h4>
    </br>   
        @foreach($funcionarios as $fun)
            @if($fun->removido != 1)
        <center><div style="display: table-row;">

        <p style="padding-top: 10px; margin-top: 10px; float: left;">{{$fun->name}}</p>
        <input id="ajaxValueFuncionario+{{$fun->id}}" value="{{$fun->id}}" type="hidden" name="">
        <div style="float: left;">
        <button onclick="attachProjetoFuncionario()" id="ajaxAdicionarFuncionario"
        class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-left: 10px; padding: 6px; padding-right: 12px; padding-left: 12px; padding-bottom: 10px; ">+</button>
        <button type="button"
        class="btn btn-primary" style="padding: 6px; padding-right: 16px; padding-left: 16px; padding-bottom: 10px; ">-</button>
        </div>
        </div></center>
        @endif
        @endforeach 
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Fim da Div Escolher Funcionários -->
```

A framework em que estou usando de ambiente de trabalho é o Laravel, com estrutura MVC. As rotas e controllers que relacionam tudo isso está funcionando tudo completamente, fiz alguns testes para saber disso antes.

A minha dúvida em específico é como posso chamar corretamente a minha variável, que no caso é a "ajaxValueFuncionario" para algo como "ajaxValueFuncionario" concatenado com variável "$fun->id", sendo esta última variável em php que varia de acordo com o novo  que é impresso na página para funcionário do loop @foreach.

Essa declaração correta eu já fiz em:

```html
(...)
<input id="ajaxValueFuncionario+{{$fun->id}}" value="{{$fun->id}}" type="hidden" name="">
(...)
```

Agora preciso saber como fazer algo parecido dentro do script.

Obrigado a atenção.

Comment: Porque não passa do id directamente à função <button onclick="attachProjetoFuncionario('ajaxValueFuncionario'+{{$fun->id}})" e na sua função recebe como parâmetro function attachProjetoFuncionario(idfunc) por exemplo

Comment: Obrigado! Utilizei algo baseado na sua ideia e funcionou sim!